# Grails 2.4.4. hierarchical domain structure: find

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have hierarchical folder structure:

```
class Folder {
    String name;
    List<Folder> subfolders;
```

I want to select all Folders, which are not subfolder.
How can I write findAll method/query in jpql like :

```
SELECT * FROM folder WHERE folder.id NOT IN (
SELECT folder.id FROM folder INNER JOIN folder_folder ON folder.id = folder_folder.folder_id);
```

I don't have parent field;

something like this?

```
Folder.findAll("from Folder as folder where folder.id not in subfolders");
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change domain to one-to-many;
Just add     static mappedBy = [subLevels: "parentFolder"]

```
class Folder {
        String name;
        Folder parentFolder;
        List<Folder> subfolders;
        static mappedBy = [subLevels: "parentFolder"]
```

And findAll method will be

```
Folder.findAll("from Folder as folder where folder.parentFolder = null");
```